# How to use wrapper (sub routing) in React Router dom which has a list of routes inside

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a small issue with a sub routing in react-router-dom

In my case, I have 3 types of different containers as MainContainer.jsx, LoginContainer.jsx and RegisterContainer.jsx

Inside of all of these containers exist sub routing

For now, in my App.js file  just only a 3 routes

When I try to visit routes in the LoginContainer.jsx and if I don't have an exact flag on the parent route the login routes do not render

On another side when I try to visit a register route and if the login parent routes have an exact flag I have the same error

I were trying to switch exact and strick flags on all of the parent routes in the App.js

But it has not resolved my problem

There it is my components

My App.js file

```
<Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={MainContainer}/>
                <Route path='/login' component={LoginContainer}/>
                <Route path='/login/:type/register' component={RegisterContainer}/>
            </Switch>
```

My LoginContainer

```
<Router history={history}>
            <div className="login">
                <LoginHeaderNavigation/>
                <div className="login-page-wrapper">
                    <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={match.url} component={Login}/>
                            <Route exact path={`${match.url}/:type`} component={LoginType}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Suspense>
                    <LoginFooter/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
```

My RegisterContainer

```
<Router history={history}>
            <div className='register-page'>
                <RegisterHeaderNavigation/>
                <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/login/:type/register' component={Register}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Suspense>
            </div>
        </Router>
```

And last one MainContainer

```
<Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Explore}/>
                    <Route path='/adventure-blog/:slug/:id' component={Blog}/>
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` component renders ***the first*** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. This means that path order and specificity matters!! You should order the routes within a `Switch` component from *more* specific to *less* specific. If done correctly there is almost no need at all for the `exact` prop.

Also, if any of the routed components are rendering nested routes then *exactly* matching the path prefix necessarily precludes the matching of sub-routes. In other words, if exactly matching `"/login"` to render `LoginContainer` and then you try to navigate to `"/login/sometype"` the path no longer exactly matches and the `LoginContainer` is unmounted.

App

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login/:type/register' component={RegisterContainer} />
  <Route path='/login' component={LoginContainer} />
  <Route path='/' component={MainContainer} />
</Switch>
```

You really only need a single router wrapping the app to provide a routing context to all the routing components. I suggest removing the nested routers in the other containers. The nested routes should use the `path` value from the `match` object, `url` is used to build any nested links.

LoginContainer

```
<div className="login">
  <LoginHeaderNavigation />
  <div className="login-page-wrapper">
    <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:type`} component={LoginType} />
        <Route path={match.path} component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
    <LoginFooter />
  </div>
</div>
```

RegisterContainer

```
<div className='register-page'>
  <RegisterHeaderNavigation />
  <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={match.path} component={Register} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
</div>
```

MainContainer

```
<Suspense fallback={<></>}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/adventure-blog/:slug/:id" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="/" component={Explore} />
  </Switch>
</Suspense>
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-wrapper-sub-routing-in-react-router-dom-which-has-a-list-of-routes]